# How to remove vb.net Richtextbox lines that not contains specific text?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I use the next code to remove lines from Richtextboxes but that way i can only tell what line to remove. I need to remove all lines that not contains specific text, can this be done with some edits of my code?

1st piece:

```
Private Property lineToBeRemovedlineToBeRemoved As Integer
```

2nd piece:

```
Dim lineToBeRemoved As Integer = 0
        lineToBeRemovedlineToBeRemoved = lineToBeRemoved - 0
        Dim str As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(lineToBeRemoved)
        RichTextBox1.Find(str & vbCr)
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will remove any line from a richtextbox `RichTextbox1` that does not contain "Test" on it. Remember to add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` to the top of your code.

```
Private Sub RemoveLines()
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    lines = RichTextBox1.Lines.ToList
    Dim FilterText = "Test"

    For i As Integer = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Not Regex.IsMatch(lines(i), FilterText) Then
            lines.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next

    RichTextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is not close. You should start over. Use a for loop to go through the RichTextBox lines. If the text is not in a line, then delete it. Tip: It may be easier to go from the last line to the first to avoid problems when deleting.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RTB.Select(RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(2), RTB.Lines(2).Count)
    RTB.SelectionLength = RTB.Lines(2).Length + 1
    RTB.SelectedText = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I applied to my prog and it work good.
When use, just ... call dels("unwanted") ==> Line which contain unwanted word will disappear.

```
    Private Sub dels(sw As String)
    Dim ud As String = ""  'for keep all we need
    Dim cn As Integer = 0 'for avoid empty line 
    For Each line As String In RichTextBox1.Lines 'for every line in reichtextbox
        If Len(line) > 5 Then 'if that line got more than 5 character
            If InStr(line.ToLower, sw.ToLower) < 1 Then 'transform them to lower case for better resulted
                If cn = 1 Then ud = ud + vbCrLf 'not place new-line if it is first 
                ud = ud + line 'keep this line if not match ne want delete
                cn = 1 'turn-off first line signal
            End If
        End If
    Next
    RichTextBox1.Clear() 'empty richtextbox
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(ud) 'update richtextbox with the unwanted 
    End Sub
```